# How to measure test execution time in jest-puppeteer for suite or each test

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I have a multiple suites which have multiple tests. When I execute the tests, I want to get the test execution time for each suite and its respective test.

Note that some tests are common across multiple suites.

I expect the results

```
Suite ${suiteName} took :${} time
Suite ${suiteName} took :${} time
```

and

```
Test ${testName} took :${} time
Test ${testName} took :${} time
```

I haven't come across any solution before now.